# what is recommended for a wpf app, sql database or xml

Tags: wpf, xml, database, mvvm

I want to build a wpf app (with mvvm dp) and I need to manage a list of customers (200 customers maximum)
What is the recommended way to handle this? sql (mySql, sqlServer) or other way (xml, excel, access)?

I can see advantage in xml because its not required addition installation

Comment: How many concurrent users will you have? Does this application run on multiple machines at the same time, or only one? Do you need to share data with any other entity, and if so, how? Do you need to manage any other kind of data other than a list of customers? What kind of data does each customer record contain?

Comment: If you're using a single-user application on a single machine - why not use an **embedded** database such as [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) ?? No install (is copied as an in-process DLL with your app), and you still have a (mostly) full-blown database ....

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Its need to be one user(but not necessarily). one machine. what do you mean share with other entity?

Comment: I meant, do you need to routinely import data from, or export data to, other databases, applications, etc. Like exporting purchase order data to an accounts payable system.

Comment: How do you envision sharing the data between the multiple machines that run your application? Do they need to share or synchronize the customer data with each other? If so, you'll probably want a centralized database, like SQL Server or MySQL, assuming the different machines can talk to each other over a network. If not, an embedded database (like SQL Server Compact Edition, or SQLite), as marc_s mentions, is a good choice.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta So if there is more then one user I need to use a centralized database? and what about the data in the app? its recomeded to use DataSet ot there is a better way? thanks!

Comment: If there's more than one user, and you don't want to do weird tricks to synchronize their data (like enforcing that only one user can use the application at a time, and exporting changes from one, and importing into the others, and that's just a big headache), then yes, you need a central datastore.

Comment: Ask another question about how to store data in your application proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got multiple users on different machines, and those machines have a persistent, shared network connection (they're on the same network, for instance), then you should prefer to use a central database, like (as you mention) SQL Server or [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/). The latter is free, and the former is available in a [free edition (Express)](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) for light workloads.

If you don't need to share data between the different users of your application (you don't mind if their customer data get out of sync), then look at lightweight, embedded databases, like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) or [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142). Very simple and easy to set up and maintain, but the data stays present on a single machine.

You could build an infrastructure around manual synchronization between the different machines, sort of like how iTunes synchronizes data between your computer and iPhone whenever you plug the latter in, but trust me, that's a lot of work that's best avoided if possible. Databases have a lot of built-in multiple-users-doing-stuff-at-the-same-time logic that you want to leverage if at all possible.

Comment: you can explain me please why you dont like the xml solution? (if i dont share data and i have only one user)

Comment: Well, there's nothing really *wrong* with storing the data as XML. Lots of developers, including me, do that. I tend to prefer using existing serialization libraries with XML, though (like [ConfigurationSections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)). I often seem to outgrow straight XML pretty fast, and wish I had the power of a database right from the start. Also, databases make [relational storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

If the only thing you need to persist is a list of 200the items **and you don't see there as being any other persistent data requirements in the future**, I would say that a flat file is plenty. However, this also depends on how often that small data will be retrieved.

I am a huge proponent of SQL Server, and Express is free. But you don't want to overengineer the problem. Unless I misunderstood your question, that is my evaluation.